# How do i add values to a string array from a class?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple object-oriented program for a fictional movie theatre.
Therefore I am making a kind of list with all the movies. My issue is that I can not add genres to my genre array in the child classes to the Movies class.

Here is what I have made so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BentesBio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Movie[] moviesArray = new Movie[6];

            moviesArray[0] = new FeatureFilm { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00, Genre = { "", "" }, Cast = {} };
            moviesArray[1] = new FeatureFilm { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00 };
            moviesArray[2] = new FeatureFilm { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00 };
            moviesArray[3] = new FeatureFilm { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00 };
            moviesArray[4] = new Documentary { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00, Theme = { "", "" } };
            moviesArray[5] = new Documentary { Director = "", Country = "", Budget = 0.0, BudgetCurrency = "", BudgetDKK = 0.0, Year = 0000, Score = "", Length = 00 };


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Movie
    {
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public double Budget { get; set; }
        public string BudgetCurrency { get; set; }
        public double BudgetDKK { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }

    class FeatureFilm : Movie
    {
        public string[] Genre { get; set; }
        public string[] Cast { get; set; }
    }

    class Documentary : Movie
    {
        public string[] Theme { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead arrays (`T[]`) ... arrays are hard to expand (you need to create bigger and copy elements from old one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming languages, arrays normally are fixed size. If you don't like the size, you have to create a new one with a different size. If you want a container with a variable size, where you can add and remove elements at will, this is commonly called a list.

In C# for your purpose, that would be a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace -

```
Genre = { "", "" }
```

with -

```
Genre = new string[] { "", "" }
```

And same goes for assignment of `Theme`

And yes as per other answers you should use `List<T>` that'll give you flexibility to add random number of movies instead of a pre declared fixed count.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Movie has not got Genre you should cast Movie class to FeatureFilm class to work with Genre property. moviesArray is Movie array.